# Vaadin Chart Component Suggestion

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

I wish to have a graph similar to this [chart](https://ibb.co/dLev2p). I'm able achieve it partially, but I'm not able to get that centre count part. How to achieve the same? Do I need to use SOLIDGAUGE or PIE as ChartType?

Currently I'm using ChartType as PIE. And to achieve the hollow part in centre, I'm writing below code. [what I've achieved](https://ibb.co/eEUgQ9)

```
PlotOptionsPie plotOptions=new PlotOptionsPie();
plotOptions.setInnerSize("50%");
configuration.setPlotOptions(plotOptions);
```

But now how to put that count (985 as in image) in centre?
I tried using DataLabels but its not working.

Note: I'm using **Vaadin Charts 3.2.1**, Vaadin 7 and Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Pie chart with inner size is the way to go.

You can use the title for that purpose, and set the location of the title in the middle of the chart.

```
    Configuration conf = chart.getConfiguration();
    Title title = conf.getTitle();
    title.setText("985");
    title.setAlign(HorizontalAlign.CENTER);
    title.setVerticalAlign(VerticalAlign.MIDDLE);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm already using Title to set the title of the chart. Here [what I've achieved](https://ibb.co/eEUgQ9) you can find I've already defined the value as 'Status Chart' as heading for that.

Comment: @ShainiSinha Can you share the full code you're using? In this example, there is both vertical and horizontal alignment.

Comment: @eeq The problem with the above suggested code is that I'm already using conf.setTitle("Status Chart") to set the title of my chart.

Comment: can you use the subtitle for the "Status Chart" text?